# Slice copy is not working as expected

Tags: go, slice

In the following Go program, I am creating `mySlice1` with 6 elements in it.
`mySlice2` is initialized with 3 elements.

From `mySlice1` I am taking 1st two elements into `mySlice2`. Also using `copy` function of slice, 3 elements of `mySlice1` are overwritten to `mySlice2`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    mySlice1 := []int{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}
    mySlice2 := make([]int,3)
    mySlice2 = mySlice1[0:2]
    copy(mySlice2,mySlice1)
    fmt.Printf("%T\t%T\n", mySlice1,mySlice2)
    fmt.Println(mySlice1,mySlice2)
}
```

But while printing `mySlice2` I am getting two elements only.

```
$ go run main.go
[]int   []int
[1 3 5 7 9 11] [1 3]
```

Why is `mySlice2` not getting overwritten while using `copy` function?

Answer (score 4):

If you want `mySlice2` to have 3 elements, you should use:

```
myslice2 = mySlice1[0,3]
```

Or just:

```
copy(mySlice2,mySlice1)
```

You did create a slice with length 3, but the you then reassign it to a length of 2. You can see it using `len(mySlice2)` before and after the assignments

Answer (score 2):

You are reinitializing mySlice2 variable at this point:
`mySlice2 = mySlice1[0:2]`.

So, the previous reference to the slice with 3 elements is gone.

To remedy this, simply remove this sentence and re-run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected.

You are copying the first three values from the `mySlice1` into `mySlice2`, hence you are actually copy the memory addresses pointing to the first three items from `mySlice1` slice.

When you are declaring the `mySlice2` actually you are initializing the slice index values with zero's (this is how Go slices are working). Then you copy the first three values from slice1 into slice2. This does not means that `mySlice2` values are changed. If you change `mySlice2` 0<sup>th</sup> index to let's say 1 the `mySlice1` first value is changed accordingly, because as i mentioned the indexes are referenced by their memory addresses.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    mySlice1 := []int{0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}
    mySlice2 := make([]int,3)
    mySlice2 = mySlice1[0:2]
    mySlice2[0] = 1

    copy(mySlice2,mySlice1)
    fmt.Printf("%T\t%T\n", mySlice1,mySlice2)
    fmt.Println(mySlice1,mySlice2)

    // Output
    // [1 3 5 7 9 11] [1 3]
}
```